# Servlet Not Getting Hit In Simple JSP Application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here is my `Servlet Class`

```
package com.jsp.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/StudentRegistration")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String UserName;
            UserName =(String)request.getParameter("Name");
            // System.out.println(fnameOperator);
            String condition = "where 1=1";
            condition = condition + "and student_id = " + UserName;
            System.out.println(condition);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request,
                response);
    }

}
```

View Page to Post data in Servlet

```
<form action="StudentRegistration" method="get">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Email" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="Password" name="Password" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Gender:</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="M" />Male <input
                    type="radio" name="Gender" value="F" />Female</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Image:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="Image" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Resume:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="Resume" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Register"
                    Value="Register" /> <input type="button" name="Reset"
                    Value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This is my Servlet mapping

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>UserServlte</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jsp.servlet.UserServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UserServlte</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/StudentRegistration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

When i'm running my application, and posting data from index page(view page) to servlet i'm getting `404` page not found.

I'm very very new to JAVA development, please help.

Comment: What container do you use?

Comment: should i use container? and where it has to use?? can you give me some link? @yurko

Comment: did you implemen the init() method in your servlet or not

Comment: no, i didn't impliment init() method  @PacMan

Answer (score 0):

Guess there's a typo in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserServlte</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jsp.servlet.UserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlte</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/StudentRegistration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your servlet class is called `UserServlet` but on the web.xml you refer to it as `UserServlte`